# Changing Camera focus in Azure Maps in Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-maps

I'm using Azure Maps in my android application, is there a way to programmatically set the MapOptions which contains target latitude, longitude, and zoom values to the AzureMap object.

I'm able to set those values in XML but not able to do in Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

The MapOptions object is the java representation of the MapControl's initial attributes.

If you want to directly construct a MapControl you can use the MapOptions.Builder to build a MapOptions object and pass it to the MapControl constructor.

Comment: I actually want to change the cameraTargetLat and cameraTargetLng value inside getMapAsync where I have reference to the azureMap object. So I created MapOption object with new Lat and Lng value but not able to add the same to maps